# How to group multi-displays in windows?

Tags: display

I have three 19'' monitors. Each of them has 1280 x 1024 resolution. Is it possible to group my monitors so that windows treat them like one monitor with 3840 x 1024 resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. But your video card must support **Span Mode**.

Modern cards tend to. Below is a GeForce4 MX 440 set to Span Mode. Both Direct3D and OpenGL offer support for Span Mode and **3D applications can stretch across both displays** (yes, this includes games, provided their code doesn't explicitly disable it).

**Only limitation:** Make sure both monitors have same resolutions and refresh rate.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use extended mode in display properties. There should be a checkbox along the lines of "Extend my Windows Desktop onto this Monitor" which you will see once you select the additional monitor in display properties.

Comment: that would work partially. Windows applications still think that they have three monitors.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which version of Windows, but I think Windows by default maximizing across all three windows doesnt occur natively until Windows 7. At least I'm not able to get that functionality with my Windows Vista Home Basic (hey, it was free!)

Comment: I am using windows 7. How do I enable it??